# [Rails]Update his informations as a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I train to use rails. I have create a system of authentication for the user, of course, he can to access at this informations. But if he's connected, he can to update his informations. And now, i have a problem, the redirection with the patch work however there's no update of his informations for exemple pseudo. The user put a new pseudo, but it doesn't update. But it works in console.

code of controller sessions :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

def show
    @page = User.find(params[:id])

end

def update
    User.find(params[:id]).update name: params[:name]
    redirect_to "/profil/#{current_user.id}"
end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    # If the user exists AND the password entered is correct.
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      # Save the user id inside the browser cookie. This is how we keep the user
      # logged in when they navigate around our website.
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
    # If user's login doesn't work, send them back to the login form.
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

code of show:

```
<h1>Profil</h1>
 
<% if current_user && @page.id == current_user.id %>
<%= form_tag "/profil/#{@page.id}", method: "patch" do %>
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="name" value="<%= current_user.name %>" /></li>
    <li><%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb) %></li>
  <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer mon profil" />
</ul>
<% end
else
 %>
<%= @page.name %>
<br>
<%= image_tag @page.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
 
<% end %>
```

code of routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see <a href="http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html" rel="nofollow">http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html</a>

    get '/signup' => 'users#new'
    post '/users' => 'users#create'

      get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/profil/:id' => 'sessions#show'
  patch '/profil/:id' => 'sessions#update'
end
```

After lot of tests, I don't find my mistakes.

Sorry, if my english is no great because I'm french.

thank you in advance ^^

Comment: What if you try that in console, does it work? `User.find(uid).update(name: 'joe')`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev it works in console.

Comment: Then it should work in controller too. Must be something else going on (for example, actually submitted data is wrong or something).

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Have you an idea for the submitted data who is wrong  ?

Comment: Me, I don't have any idea. You should have ideas, you have all the data and logs.

Comment: Maybe show your User model, also check for errors, most likely you have a validation error. Also if you are using Rails 4 you can try update! instead of update, this will throw an exception, then you can see what went wrong.